# Why my applied changes in urls.py is not reflecting after I tried reloading the Django web page?

Tags: python, django

In views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home_page(request):
    
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello, World</h1>")
```

In urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .veiws import home_page

urlpatterns = [
     path('', home_page),
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: post the error screenshot please

Comment: you have a syntax error at "from .veiws import home_page", it should be views

Comment: Oh, sorry I tried everything but due to this silly mistake and I am really sorry for not checking.

Answer (score 0):

Your import says .veiws instead of .views